# How do I get 4 children that are variables

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am trying to get the some variables out of a XML document using XPath the problem is they are different each time (variable) but there is always 4 of them I just am not sure how to get the data out of the XML document. [image]

I am not that good with XML or XPath but this is what I have come up with so far and I am stuck because I don't know how to loop the cell to get the data out of it.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    string sElementInfo = string.Empty;
                    var cell = xml.XPathSelectElement(
                    "oms:outputTree/oms:command[@text='Discriminant']/" +
                    "oms:heading[@text='Analysis 1']/" +
                    "oms:heading[@text='Classification Statistics']/" +
                    "oms:pivotTable[@text='Classification Function Coefficients']/" +
                    "oms:dimension[@text='(Variables)']",
                    nsManager);

                    if (cell != null)
                    {
                        sStatement1 = (string)cell.Attribute("varName");
                    }

                }
```

The e4, e17, and e22 will be different each time so I can not find them by that name, also the boxed "number" will be different each time also so I am not sure how to get that either. 
I though if I looped the whole document but then I cant figure out how to get to the next cell. Any help would be great!
Thank you.

if this helps this is what I normally do with xpath the problem is I don't know what the varName's are going to be so I can pick out the rest of the data, this was from a different XML document but similar:

```
    var xml = XDocument.Load(@"c:/temp/descriptives_table.xml");
            var nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());

            nsManager.AddNamespace(
                "oms",
                "http://www.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/xml/oms");
            try
            {
                SqlDataReader sqlDR = sqlCom.ExecuteReader();
                while (sqlDR.Read())
                {
                    string sElementInfo = string.Empty;
                    var cell = xml.XPathSelectElement(
                    "oms:outputTree/oms:command[@text='Regression']/" +
                    "oms:heading[@text='uid = " + sqlDR.GetDouble(0) + ".00']/" +
                    "oms:pivotTable[@text='Coefficients']/" +
                    "oms:dimension/oms:category/oms:dimension/oms:category[@text='(Constant)']/" +
                    "oms:dimension/oms:group/oms:category/oms:cell",
                    nsManager);
                    if (cell != null)
                    {
                        var number = (string)cell.Attribute("number");
                        sElementInfo = sqlDR.GetDouble(0) + ", " + number + ", ";
                        //Console.WriteLine(sqlDR.GetDouble(0).ToString() + " (Constant) " + number);
                        for (int i = 1; i < 37; i++)
                        {

                            var xElement = xml.XPathSelectElement(
                            "oms:outputTree/oms:command[@text='Regression']/" +
                            "oms:heading[@text='uid = " + sqlDR.GetDouble(0) + ".00']/" +
                            "oms:pivotTable[@text='Coefficients']/" +
                            "oms:dimension/oms:category/oms:dimension/oms:category[@text='e" + i +"']/" +
                            "oms:dimension/oms:group/oms:category/oms:cell",
                            nsManager);
                            if (xElement != null)
                            {
                                var nElement = (string)xElement.Attribute("text");
                                sElementInfo = sElementInfo + nElement + ", ";
                                //Console.WriteLine(sqlDR.GetDouble(0).ToString() + " e" + i + " " + nElement);
                                //Console.WriteLine(" ");
                            }
                        }
                        //Console.WriteLine(sElementInfo.Remove(sElementInfo.Length-2));
```

Comment: Could you please provide some sample XML to work on.

Comment: I tried to add the XML it, not sure how that is why I added a image. The XML is very long.

Comment: You simply want to geht the `number`?

Comment: I need the varName and number the parts that are in red boxes.

Comment: Then please create a pastie or gist or similar, with the xml, and link to it.

Comment: Robert is there a place where I can post it?

Comment: Searching for "pastie" or "gist" would have given you pastie.org and gist.github.com respectively. However, you seem to have been given an answer already, without posting the XML.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8541596 is the XML, I tried what is suggested below and it comes up with way too many

Comment: That is not valid XML. You seem to have marked everything in the xml view in Internet Explorer and posted that. Please do view source or similar instead, if you want to post the XML, so you don't get the extra characters added by the xml view in IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use `System.Xml.Linq`

```
        var doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

        XNamespace ns = @"http://www.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/xml/oms";

        var pivotTables = doc.Descendants(ns + "pivotTable");

        // identify the pivottable by the text "Classified Function Coefficients"
        var theTable = pivotTables.Where(table => table.Attribute( "text").Value == "Classification Function Coefficients");

        // first dimension
        var dimension = theTable.Elements(ns + "dimension").First();

        // first dimensions categories
        var categories = dimension.Elements(ns + "category");

        foreach (var category in categories)
        {
            // at index 5 there exists a category without varname and text="(Constant)"
            // skip it
            if(!category.Attributes().Any(attr => attr.Name == "varName"))
                continue;

            // here's the varname                
            var varName = category.Attribute( "varName").Value;

            if (varName.StartsWith("("))
                continue;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(varName);
            var cells = category.Descendants(ns + "cell");

            foreach (var cell in cells)
            {
                // here's the number of the cell
                var number = cell.Attribute("number").Value;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(number);
            }
        }
```

Output:

- e9
- 0.16392050172531
- 0.13063860362111
- 0.28542086095635
- e18
- 0.32758593355552
- 0.071751070799144
- 0.4532773907448
- e33
- 0.16067704682981
- 0.254227301797
- 0.01461475905339
- e34
- 0.3033365693718
- 0.12043800410649
- 0.58905116575338

Comment: Do be vary that "category" sounds like a possibly common element name and could therefore occur on other places in the xml. This would not work if that was the case. However, a slight modification of it would probably be fine.

Comment: Yes category is all over this XML document.

Comment: @robert.westerlund that's right. But for this case I'm pretty sure that is is adequate.

Comment: @user1221399 that's a normal behavior of XML files. What robert means is, that `category`would be used in another context than the shown.

Comment: It seems not, since user1221399 has stated that category occurs frequently. I have upvoted your answer already, but I do suggest updating it to use only the category element in the correct part of the xml (unless, of course, if user1221339 actually wants all categories given that they all have these values (just guessing, but perhaps all dimensions?)). Only user1221339 can answer this, of course.

Comment: When I run this I get too many responses to sort out, category is shown too many times is there way to use linq and start from variables child?

Comment: Its a very large XML document and category is in there many time, so I don't think this will work.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Now I identify the pivottable by "Classified Function Coefficients" and take the first dimension. The rest is as seen in the old example

Comment: Its getting hung up on dimension but I think its just a matter of me playing with it. I will get back to you in a few

Comment: var pivotTables = doc.Descendants("pivotTable"); is coming up null

Comment: This is probably because of not using the xml namespace in the query. If you edit your original question with a link to a gist or paste of your xml (correctly formatted) it would be easier to assist you.

Comment: gist.github.com/anonymous/8541596 is where I posted the XML its very large just a warning.

Comment: As I mentioned as a comment above, that XML is invalid. I'm guessing that you're copying all the contents of the XML view in Internet Explorer or similar, which includes some extra characters used to expand/collapse nodes. Please only post the XML (you should be able to get to the xml if you do View Source on the xml view), to actually make it usable.

Comment: I also added this: nsManager.AddNamespace(
                    "oms",
                    "http://www.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/xml/oms");

Comment: Normally when I use these IBM files I have to add: var nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());

                nsManager.AddNamespace(
                    "oms",
                    "http://www.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/xml/oms");

Comment: Glad you have it solved. For alternative methods, you could also use the XPathSelectElements extension method which you'll get if you add 'using System.Xml.XPath;'